# How to use StreamBuilder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, location

I tried implementing this code in my project, here is the link to that https://gitmemory.com/issue/DarshanGowda0/GeoFlutterFire/16/472098428

This is my Scaffold.

```
Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async  {

             await GetusersLocation();

              },
              child: Center(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                ),
              ),
            ),

            StreamBuilder(
              stream: stream,
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshots) {
                if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
                    snapshots.hasData) {
                  print(snapshots.data);
                  return Container();
                } else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),

          ],
        ),
      )),
```

Here is my GetusersLocation()

```
Future<void> GetusersLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    lat = position.latitude;
    long = position.longitude;
  }
```

Here is my initState()

```
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream;



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    geo = Geoflutterfire();
    var radius = BehaviorSubject.seeded(1.0);
    GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: 26.8462924, longitude: 81.0042322);
    stream = radius.switchMap((rad) {
      var collectionReference = _firestore.collection('locations');
      return geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference).within(
          center: center, radius: rad, field: 'position', strictMode: true);
    });
  }
```

I'm getting this printed in my console.

> [Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'].

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a List of `DocumentSnapshot` which is normal, your data is in the DocumentSnapshot.
You can use the List of `DocumentSnapshot` in a ListView like so.

```dart
 StreamBuilder(
    stream: stream,
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshots) {
      if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
          snapshots.hasData) {
        print(snapshots.data);
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshots.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshots.data[index];
            Map location = doc.data; // this is your data which is probably a map
            return Text(
              location.toString(),
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Hey! thank you so much for answering this question, it worked for me! But i have a question, it worked only when i had put the code(initializing the stream) in initstate(). When I made a separate function, and called that when a button was pressed, i got nothing printed in my console, no warnings or errors, nothing. Just curious, why is this happening?

Comment: can you post your function so i can take a look

Comment: Future<dynamic> getnearbyusers() async {
    await GetusersLocation();
    geo = Geoflutterfire();
    var radius = BehaviorSubject.seeded(1.0);
    GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(latitude: lat, longitude: long);
    stream = radius.switchMap((rad) {
      var collectionReference = _firestore.collection('locations');
      return geo.collection(collectionRef: collectionReference).within(
          center: center, radius: rad, field: 'position', strictMode: true);
    });
  }

Comment: your function is not returning a Stream and it does not have setState either

Comment: oh,umm..but it is initializing the stream? i mean, is it necessary to always return a stream when initialized?

Comment: Ohh since you're initializing, you should setState so the StreamBuilder can be updated with the stream

Comment: Thank you so much man! i understood now.  Happy coding :)